# Why does my row size exceed the allowed maximum of 8060 bytes

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table in SQL Server 2012, Web Edition:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyTable] 
(
     [Id]               INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
     [Created]          DATETIME       DEFAULT (getdate()) NOT NULL,
     [RefId]            INT            NULL,
     [Name]             NVARCHAR (128) NULL,
     [Email]            NVARCHAR (128) NULL,
     [ImageUrl]         NVARCHAR (256) NULL,
     [Url]              VARCHAR (256)  NULL,
     [Age]              TINYINT        NULL,
     [Country]          VARCHAR (6)    NULL,
     [Location]         NVARCHAR (192) NULL,
     [People]           INT            NULL,
     [Categories]       NVARCHAR (128) NULL,
     [Block]            BIT            DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,
     [GeneratedRevenue] INT            NULL,
     [IsFemale]         BIT            DEFAULT ((1)) NULL,
     [HasInstalled]     BIT            NULL,
     [Keywords]         VARCHAR (128)  NULL,
     [Brands]           NVARCHAR (512) NULL,
     [Source]           TINYINT        NULL,
     [Alias]            VARCHAR (65)   NULL,

     PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

As far as I gather, the total size should be 3175 bytes; but I regularly get the following error, when updating the table:

> Cannot create a row of size 8068 which is greater than the allowable maximum row size of 8060.

How does the above result in a row size of 8068?

**Edit**: I should mention that this table has been altered, uses Change Tracking and has four indexes.

Also, if I copy the contents to a new table with the same definition, no errors occur for a while, but do come back.

Comment: Perhaps you have a trigger on the insert and the problem is happening on another table.

Comment: Just guessing is this entirely new table or it was altered? It looks like in the past there was different type (maybe NVARCHAR(MAX)).

Comment: Or an indexed view?

Comment: I edited my question above to answer your questions.
@lad2025, why does it look like there was a different size in the past?

Comment: Where'd you come up with the 3175 number? I counted and got 3641. Also, do you have a view which joins this to another table? Perhaps it is the combination of data which is over the top.

Comment: See http://rusanu.com/2011/10/20/sql-server-table-columns-under-the-hood/

Comment: @Eli I may have gotten something wrong when calculating; my point was that I couldn't get near the 8060 boundary. I get this error when doing a simple update on a single field, no joins involved.

Comment: @Scarabas understood.

Comment: Check out the following link: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345371%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: What do you get if you run the following query? `SELECT sc.name, sipc.leaf_offset, sipc.max_inrow_length
FROM    sys.partitions sp
  JOIN sys.system_internals_partition_columns sipc ON sp.partition_id = sipc.partition_id
  JOIN sys.columns sc ON sc.column_id = sipc.partition_column_id AND sc.OBJECT_ID = sp.OBJECT_ID
WHERE sp.OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID('MyTable')`

Comment: I didn't think that SQL Server 2012 *had* this limit? Checking the [documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186981(v=sql.105).aspx), I think it's actually okay for a table with VARCHAR and NVARCHAR to exceed this limit. Do you have a clustered index that includes any of your character columns?

Comment: @sgmoore I get roughly the same columns as for table creation, a few of them appear more than once. The total max_inrow_length is 3965.

Comment: @MattGibson I do have an index on Name and Email, but even with that on top of the numbers above, I can't get to the 8060 boundary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You say you use Change Tracking. Are you - by any chance - ignoring the versioning part of Change Tracking, and resetting the entries by doing the following?

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTable disable change_tracking
ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTable enable change_tracking
```

If so, you may have a suspect. Change Tracking adds an 8 bit column behind the scenes every time you reenable Change Tracking, which is dropped if it already exists. Since dropping a column is just a meta operation, you may have a large number of dropped 8 bit columns lurking behind the scenes, depending on the frequency with which you reenable Change Tracking.

To check this, look at the `system_internals_partition_columns` view and see if you have a large number of `is_dropped` colums. There could be more reasons for having many of those, but this way of using Change Tracking is one of them.

I see Remus Rusanu is linking to a good article in a comment ([rusanu.com/2011/10/20/sql-server-table-columns-under-the-hoo‌​d](http://rusanu.com/2011/10/20/sql-server-table-columns-under-the-hoo%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bd)): the queries he lists should be what you need to see if the above is the case.

**Edit:**
In case you need to delete the dropped columns, you can rebuild the clustered index for the table(s) that have many dropped columns. This means that rebuilding the  clustered index for `MyTable` will relieve you of your symptom.

Comment: I do use Change Tracking this way, yes. Initially to avoid storing unnecessary versions, since the volume is huge. I have ~64000 is_dropped entries in the queries you're linking to, and they grow every time I enable CT. I guess I have to use a different approach. Thanks man!!!